# Is my answer too specific medically?

Tags: discussion, answers

[My answer here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/5588/1908) deals with the basic outline of technique to deal with a shoulder dislocation in the backcountry. My goal was to be as informative as was reasonable but not replace actually having the right knowledge and training yourself. Yet is this getting too specific medically for this type of site?
If so I don't know if the [original question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/4208/1908) is appropriately answerable in it's current form.

This could also apply to several other first-aid and medically related question and answers.

These meta questions are related, but not the same:

- [Should we get a closing reason for questions that ask for medical advice?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/448/1908)
- [authority and medical questions](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/424/1908)

Comment: I'm totally confused as to what were supposed to do with meta questions like this. No one answers, the moderators are never around. Sometimes I answer but who's to say I'm right?

Comment: @Liam - Yeah meta seems to be quite vacant these days. And it also seems many once-regular users are rarely, if ever on the Great Outdoors anymore.

Comment: Having seen activity over the last couple of years wax and wane, Spring to Summer is our lowest attendance. Some sites don't vary so much annually, but we are (quite logically, I suppose) very seasonal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem at all… medically or otherwise.

Our self-imposed moratorium against "medical advice" is often overdone — It is really geared towards users requesting or dispensing ***personalized*** medical courses of action/treatment where the situation really requires someone trained in diagnosing your situation ***specifically*** to dispense the correct, responsible advice.

That's not to say that some article on the Internet should be used to as a replacement for the proper assessment and treatment of a dislocated shoulder… **but you were very clear about that.**

If you think about it, one might say it's equally ludicrous for people to take their life into their own hands by taking "safe hiking advice" from a site like this. But nobody is suggesting that we shouldn't be allowed to talk about this stuff either.

Posting this information can only make this site better. Whether the subject is medical knowledge or legal situations or whatever, not being qualified or "licensed" in some field doesn't mean I should remain ignorant of the subject altogether. Let's get over these "medical questions" being a trigger point of something we should every discuss in any form. Enjoy.